# Subsetting columns from the data frame in R

Tags: r, factors

I have relatively easy question regarding the subsetting columns in R.

I have two data frames, dat1 and dat2:

```
>dat1
      cities countries areakm2 populationk
1   Shanghai     China    2643       21766
2    Beijing     China    1368       21500
3        NYC       USA Unknown        8406
4         LA       USA    1302        3884
5     London        UK    1737     Unknown
6 Manchester        UK     116         255

> dat2
  Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
```

Then, if I'd like to subset the first column from the dat1 I get the following:

```
> dat1[,1]
[1] Shanghai   Beijing    NYC        LA         London     Manchester
Levels: Beijing LA London Manchester NYC Shanghai
> class(dat1[,1])
[1] "factor
```

However, if I do the same thing with dat2 I'll get a vector, not a factor.

```
> dat2[,1]
[1] 41 36 12 18 NA
> class(dat2[,1])
[1] "integer"
```

I can't understand what the difference is between these two cases. I assume that this is something to do with data types (in dat1 the first column consists of characters, while in dat2 of integers  )

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualy both are vectors. One of factors and one of integers. If you want R to see them as characters (another type like factors or integers) you should use

stringsAsFactors = FALSE

In the creation of your data.frame

Comment: But I'm wondered why R shows the output differently in these cases?

Comment: That's R's way to display a vector of factors, it shows the underlying levels. But in further calculations, they will both be treated in the same way.